Read in an sql.gz file using R
I have been handed an sql.gz file that I need to open and analyse using R. A preview of the original dataframe (the one saved as an sql.gz file) is supposed to have 6-7 columns.
I have never used SQL before and do not have SQL installed on my computer and want to save this file as an R dataframe. I tried to unzip the file using the code below but it saves the dataframe in 2 columns, dumping all the variables into one of those two columns.
df_unzip = R.utils::gunzip("df.sql.gz")
df = read_file("df.sql")
x = gsub(',\\r\\', '\n', df, fixed=TRUE)
df_final = read.csv(text=x)

Is there an easy way to read an sql.gz file into R and save it as an R dataframe?

The (probable) best way is to install mariadb (or similar) on your system, and restore the database from the sql file (or use a (cloud)server database instance to load the sql if you cannot install on your own system). Then use the RMariaDB and the DBI to connect to the databse, download/combine relevant  tables/data and store the result in a data.frame.

Another suggestion is: If you don't want to to go through the trouble of setting up (even temporary) your own sql server instance / MariaDB or anything: Can you ask the person who handed you the data to perhaps export it into an "easier" format (like Excel, CSV, Text)? Depending on how often you need to analyse the data this might be the easiest way...
